# XSLT add child node and move children node outside

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an input XML below:

```
<Dogs>
   <Group Name="Cuties">
      <Dog Breed="Beagle">
         <Detail1>...</Detail1>
      </Dog>
      <Dog Breed="French Bulldog">
         <Detail1>...</Detail1>
      </Dog>
   </Group>
   <Group Name="Lovable">
      <Dog Breed="Labrador">
         <Detail1>...</Detail1>
      </Dog>
      <Dog Breed="Terrier">
         <Detail1>...</Detail1>
      </Dog>
   </Group>
   <Group Name="Bad">
      <Dog Breed="S">
         <Detail1>...</Detail1>
      </Dog>
      <Dog Breed="D">
         <Detail1>...</Detail1>
      </Dog>
   </Group>
</Dogs>
```

My desired output is to add another child node inside `<Dog>` and move them out of `<Group>`. The new child node should be the value of the `Name` attribute of their group. This should only affect `Cuties` and `Lovable` groups

```
<Dogs>
      <Dog Breed="Beagle">
         <Detail1>...</Detail1>
         <Detail2>Cuties</Detail2>
      </Dog>
      <Dog Breed="French Bulldog">
         <Detail1>...</Detail1>
         <Detail2>Cuties</Detail2>
      </Dog>
      <Dog Breed="Labrador">
         <Detail1>...</Detail1>
         <Detail2>Lovable</Detail2>
      </Dog>
      <Dog Breed="Terrier">
         <Detail1>...</Detail1>
         <Detail2>Lovable</Detail2>
      </Dog>
      <Group Name="Bad">
          <Dog Breed="S">
             <Detail1>...</Detail1>
          </Dog>
          <Dog Breed="D">
             <Detail1>...</Detail1>
          </Dog>
      </Group>
</Dogs>
```

I'm just starting to learn XSLT and it would be a great help to figure this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with an identity template, then add a template that matches the groups of dogs that should be omitted in the output:

```
<xsl:template match="Group[@Name = 'Cuties' or @Name = 'Lovable']">
```

and another that gives special treatment to the `Dog` elements that are in those groups:

```
<xsl:template match="Group[@Name = 'Cuties' or @Name = 'Lovable']/Dog">
```

namely, add a `Detail2` element as their last child element.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml"  omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="Group[@Name = 'Cuties' or @Name = 'Lovable']">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Group[@Name = 'Cuties' or @Name = 'Lovable']/Dog">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <Detail2>
                <xsl:value-of select="../@Name"/>
            </Detail2>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Identity template-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

If you are using XSLT 2.0, Martin Honnen has suggested you could shorten the first template to

```
<xsl:template match="Group[@Name = ('Cuties','Lovable')]">
```

The predicate will be true if the value of `@Name` is the same as one of the strings in the sequence.

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Dogs>
   <Dog Breed="Beagle">
      <Detail1>...</Detail1>
      <Detail2>Cuties</Detail2>
   </Dog>
   <Dog Breed="French Bulldog">
      <Detail1>...</Detail1>
      <Detail2>Cuties</Detail2>
   </Dog>
   <Dog Breed="Labrador">
      <Detail1>...</Detail1>
      <Detail2>Lovable</Detail2>
   </Dog>
   <Dog Breed="Terrier">
      <Detail1>...</Detail1>
      <Detail2>Lovable</Detail2>
   </Dog>
   <Group Name="Bad">
      <Dog Breed="S">
         <Detail1>...</Detail1>
      </Dog>
      <Dog Breed="D">
         <Detail1>...</Detail1>
      </Dog>
   </Group>
</Dogs>
```

Try this solution online [here](http://xsltransform.net/94rmq6y).

---

**EDIT**

> is the purpose of identity template, to copy all as is?

Yes, exactly. If the identy template is the only template in your stylesheet, then all of the input is copied unchanged.

Comment: Nice one, as you have used `version="2.0"` you could shorten the predicates to say `[@Name = ('Cuties', 'Lovable')]`.

Comment: is the purpose of identity template, to copy all as is?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for the suggestion! Since we do not know what the OP uses, I have made the stylesheet 1.0, but still pointed out the XSLT 2.0 shorthand.

Comment: i use version 1 but thanks for suggesting also version 2

Comment: @RojBeraña Yes, that's right. Please see the edit to my answer. If you plan to ask further XSLT questions, please make sure you mention the version of XSLT you are using. This makes it easier to answer the question.

Comment: one more thing, a lot apply-templates have been done, is there a rule on how they were ordered on the xslt? like last one written at the xslt will be executed first?

Comment: @RojBeraña Do you mean `xsl:apply-templates` or `xsl:template`? The order of templates in a stylesheet does not matter. They way it works is, roughly: for every item in the input, the XSLT processor looks for the one template that matches this item best. Only then are the contents of this template executed. On the other hand, the instructions _inside_ `xsl:template` (`xsl:apply-templates`, for example) are always executed in order, from top to bottom.